# What is $\{0,1\}^I$, where $I$ is a finite subset of the natural numbers?

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am given a subset $I \subset \mathbb{N}$, where $I$ is assumed to be finite.

What does the notation $\{0,1\}^I$ mean?
Is it simply the power set? Or is it something else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To extend the answers below, $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ for example can be identified with all binary sequences .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $A^B$ is commonly used to denote the set of all mappings from $B$ to $A$.

This notation is used because, if $A$ and $B$ are both finite, the cardinality of $A^B$ is simply $$\left|A^B\right|=|A|^{|B|}$$

Comment: Thanks this works

Answer (score 0):

It is the set of functions from $I$ to $\{0,1\}$. This has nothing to do with $I$ being finite or a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: There is, however, a very close link to the power set of $I$.